# Can I resize an ag-grid column using the keyboard?

Tags: ag-grid

An accessibility issue was raised in which the user should be able to resize a column while focus is on a header cell.  I don't see any built-in support for this.  Perhaps it can be handled through custom code.  Has anyone attempted this?

Comment: I need this as well. The way we do it is that you can tab to focus the grip handle in the column, and then ctrl + left arrow / right arrow to size it up and down. I can't see a way just yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is already provided. Go to [ag-grid demo page](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php)

1. Navigate to column header using arrow key
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> - column menu will be displayed

   [image]
3. Use arrow key to select `Autosize` the current OR all columns.

> Although you cannot increase / decrease the size as per you choice this way.